# Long division layout in French-speaking Switzerland

Tags: division

This question is addressed to those familiar with mathematics teaching in French-speaking Switzerland.

The [main textbook](https://www.musee-ecoles.ch/de/livres/l-016-mm-arithmetique-au-degre-moyen-1962-mamin) in use in grades 3 to 5 in the canton of Vaud from 1957 to about 1972 appears to use the German layout for long division rather than the typical French one.

I'm curious whether this was also the practice in the other French-speaking cantons and whether usage has changed since then (presumably to agree with the practice in France).

Are there other interesting instances of Alemannic influence in math teaching? I believe I've also seen things like "55'000" for 55,000 in French-Swiss sources.

Comment: A similar question: what format is used by French-speaking Canadian schools?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar The format can be seen on page 213 of this grade 3 textbook from 1950 ( https://canadienfrancais.org/media/files/ecole/Arithmetique_3e_Clercs_de_Saint-Viateur.pdf ) or page 78 of this grade 6 textbook from 2012 ( https://archive.org/details/cinemathmathemat0000unse/page/78/mode/2up ). The general answer is that it is similar to the format in France, but without the long vertical line, and without the French practice of omitting the partial products and writing the result of each subtraction directly (called the "Italian method" in Britain).

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I'm confident that this style would have been used in French schools across Canada when these were primarily run by Catholic religious orders. However, in some provinces outside Quebec, it is entirely plausible that the English layout has since been introduced into French schools either because it was mandated by the province or appeared in poorly adapted province-specific materials translated from English. For example, here is a sixth grade test from Alberta that uses the English layout. ( https://archive.org/details/mathmatiques6ean01albe )